# Limit CROSS APPLY to certain xsi:type

Tags: xml, cross-apply, selectnodes

I have XML that I would like to shred. I am trying to CROSS APPLY and only take the QueryNode of xsi:type ReferenceNode but I don't know how to limit the .nodes to only that xsi:type.
Here is my XML

```
<QueryNode xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TableNode">
<ChildNodes>
<QueryNode xsi:type="ReferenceNode">
</QueryNode>
</ChildNodes>
</QueryNode>
```

And here is my query so far:

```
SELECT      acode, x.l.value('.', 'VARCHAR(255)')
FROM        @originals as o
CROSS APPLY o.definition_xml.nodes('QueryNode/ChildNodes/QueryNode/@xsi:type') as x(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath predicate (`[.....]`) to filter the target elements with certain criteria, for example :

```
QueryNode/ChildNodes/QueryNode/@xsi:type[.="ReferenceNode"]
```

so the entire query would look about like this :

```
SELECT      acode, x.l.value('.', 'VARCHAR(255)')
FROM        @originals as o
CROSS APPLY o.definition_xml.nodes('QueryNode/ChildNodes/QueryNode/@xsi:type[.="ReferenceNode"]') as x(l)
```

Comment: Cool , thanks! That works. However, after limiting to just that type it seems it is not possible to select that node's children.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean by "it is not possible to select that node's children"..

Comment: I mean if you take the type ReferenceNode in the cross apply you can't to a x.l.value('/ChildNodes[1]/QueryNode/NodeType', 'NVARCHAR(50)') as node_type for example.

Thanks for your help though. I have found a way to get to the results I need doing recursive CTE.